# Open source java web application framework

Tags: java

Is any such frameworks we can build on ?

It should includes good-looking user-interface.

One framework to build a complete application.

Comment: Open source java web application frameworks are almost as hard to find as Perl templating engines.

Answer (score 2):

i used Vaadin that is nice and easy
https://vaadin.com/home

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty and all have some good parts people love about. Here your main concerns seems to build a nice UI. Then, I suppose, you need something like **jQuery-UI**/***ZK***/***YUI*** or something in that area. The popular Java Web Frameworks will do little help in that regards.

After deciding on any of the UI frameworks, you can choose any popular web framework, consult your team/developers here. And look at this thread about [Most Common Java Web Frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742223/what-is-the-most-commonly-used-java-web-framework/742993#742993).

Answer (score 0):

GWT, Icefaces, Richfaces, JavaServer Faces. There are many more you can search on the internet.

Answer (score -1):

Using one framework to build the complete application depends on the type of application you are building. I will suggest the use of Java Server Faces (JSF).